# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web App (Razor Pages) SignalR - OnChange event hit multiple times on SqlDependency, for single client

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, signalrcore

I have a chat feature that works in terms of firing changes from the DB to client. However, when after more than 1 client has connected and pushed changes, the SQlDependency OnChange seems to be recursively called for each client that has connected, causing an overflow of returned responses back to all clients that trigger the OnChange event on the SqlDependency.

I have combed through this similar thread:
[**SignalR** SQLDependency Onchanged fired multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073643/signalr-sqldependency-onchanged-fired-multiple-times)

But this thread is based on an Asp.Net MVC project, which focuses more in the Hub class; I didn't even have to touch the Hub class.

Here is the project I used as a guide, but this also has the same bug/problem:
https://github.com/upretymadan45/database-change-notification-using-signal-r

My Repository:

```
public class NewCaseInternalCommentsRepository : INewCaseInternalCommentsRepository
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MySigServer> _context;

    string connectionString = "";

    public string newCaseId { get; set; }

    public NewCaseInternalCommentsRepository(IConfiguration configuration,
                                IHubContext<MySigServer> context)
    {
        connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("SigRConnection");
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<NewCaseInternalComments> GetAllThisNewCaseInternalComments()
    {

        var comments = new List<NewCaseInternalComments>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            string commandText = "SELECT id, NewCaseId, TimeStamp, UserId, UserName, UserComment FROM dbo.NewCaseInternalComments WHERE NewCaseId = '" + newCaseId + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dbChangeNotification);

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var newCaseInternalComments = new NewCaseInternalComments
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(reader["TimeStamp"].ToString()),
                    UserId = reader["UserId"].ToString(),
                    UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString(),
                    UserComment = reader["UserComment"].ToString()
                };

                comments.Add(newCaseInternalComments);
            }
        }

        return comments;
    }


    private void dbChangeNotification(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {          
        _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("refreshInternalComments");
    }

}
```

Hub:

```
public class MySigServer : Hub {   
    
    
}
```

Page controller:

```
public IActionResult OnPostRetreiveInternalComments([FromBody] NewCaseInternalComments obj)
{

     _repository.newCaseId = obj.NewCaseId.ToString();

     return new JsonResult(_repository.GetAllThisNewCaseInternalComments());
}
```

In the Page controller, I call the interface of the repo:

```
public interface INewCaseInternalCommentsRepository
    {
        List<NewCaseInternalComments> GetAllThisNewCaseInternalComments();

        string newCaseId { get; set; }
    }
```

In the startup file I've tried both AddSingleton & AddTransient for the INewCaseInternalCommentsRepository interface, with no luck with either:

```
services.AddTransient<INewCaseInternalCommentsRepository, NewCaseInternalCommentsRepository>();
```

JavaScript:

```
function OpenInternalCommentsPipe(ncID) {

    if (connection.connectionState != "Connected") {
        connection.start();
    }

    connection.on("refreshInternalComments", function () {
        loadData();
    });

    loadData();

    function loadData() {

        console.log("Hello! Something was changed!!!!");
        console.log(ncID);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Identity/Account/Manage/ManagePPS?handler=RetreiveInternalComments',
            type: "POST",

            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },

            data: JSON.stringify({
                NewCaseId: ncID
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data, response) {
                PaintInternalCommentsFromTunnel(data);                
            },

            error: (jqXHR, error) => {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
                console.log(jqXHR)
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The only other thing to mention is that the SignalR script is being called in a function (OpenInternalCommentsPipe()) that is fired within a DevExtreme Popup's OnShowing() method. I'm initializing the SingnalR js object in a global variable:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/mySigServer").build();
```

And closing the connection in the same DevExtreme Popup's OnHiding():

```
connection.stop();
```

I would like for this to only return one time for each client whenever there's a change on the table.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean that both two clients received the notification after one of them update the database? If I understood correctly, this should be expected since the code ` _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("refreshInternalComments");` is trying to send the notification to all connected clients.

Comment: Yes, but on the client side, the JavaScript is fired many times (for each client connected). So once I connect to the same socket on another client, the js that is used to refresh the comments list, is fired multiple times, sending the UI into a endless loop on the js function that is used to refresh the list with the new comments. This continues to happen even after the 2nd client is disconnected. The only way to make it execute the javascript that is fired on return, once, is to restart the project (reset the IIS server).

Comment: The example here: https://github.com/upretymadan45/database-change-notification-using-signal-r  has the same bug I'm experiencing.

Comment: How did you get the OnChange method to fire? I have the same setup in Net 5 and the dependency never fires. Even reduced query to primitive select from one table with everything fully qualified names. OnChange never fires except the Subscribe instance

Comment: @tralmix If you're using SQL Server, have you enabled the Service Broker on the DB you're using? If not, here's a good link on how to do so: http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2020/08/enable-or-disable-service-broker-in-sql.html

Comment: Broker was enabled by the DBA but the OnChange method is never called. I gave up for now and went with a polling option until I can solve this.

Comment: @tralmix did you map the singalR hub in your startup file?

In the ConfigureServices() method:
services.AddSignalR();

And in the Configure() method:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
 endpoints.MapHub<MySigServer>("/mySigServer");       
});